# How to use Lucene Luke for testing search results on more than one field?

Tags: lucene, luke

I am using Lucene Luke to test search index results and noticed that I cannot select more than one field in 'Default field' drop down list. Is this by design or we cannot use Luke tool for searching against multiple fields?

Basically I would like to know SOLR qf(query field) equivalent in Lucene.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using format `field:query`. 
For details see: https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package.description

> Lucene supports fielded data. When performing a search you can either
>   specify a field, or use the default field. The field names and default
>   field is implementation specific.
>
> You can search any field by typing the field name followed by a colon
>   ":" and then the term you are looking for.
>
> As an example, let's assume a Lucene index contains two fields, title
>   and text and text is the default field. If you want to find the
>   document entitled "The Right Way" which contains the text "don't go
>   this way", you can enter:
>
> title:"The Right Way" AND text:go or
>
> title:"The Right Way" AND go Since text is the default field, the
>   field indicator is not required.
>
> Note: The field is only valid for the term that it directly precedes,
>   so the query
>
> title:The Right Way Will only find "The" in the title field. It will
>   find "Right" and "Way" in the default field (in this case the text
>   field).